# how to override error method in c# log4net

Tags: log4net

I would like to ask if it possible to override the log methods or create a new one with extra properties in the method.

at the moment you can use it:

```
GlobalContext.Properites["Details"] = "some Info";
Log.Error("Some info",Exception);
```

I would like to use it:

```
Log.MySpecialError(Details, Message, Exception);
```

any advice will be appreciated

Ori

Comment: You're looking for extension methods.

Comment: thank you for the tip, I am searching now how can it been done with extension methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own extension method.

It must be defined in a static class, and be a static method.  E.g.

Definitions:

```
public static class Log4NetExtensions
{
    public static void MySpecialError(this Log log, string details, string message, Exception exception)
    {
        //Do something with parameters
    }
}
```

Use:

```
Log.MySpecialError(details, message, ex);
```